# Torrentflux stopped working after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, apache2

Did a clean upgrade fom 13.4. After this, torrentflux stopped working. Anyone got an idea on how to resolve it? Tried dpkg-reconfigure to setup the package. Torrentflux is not under localhost/torrentflux anymore

Comment: Is torrentflux running on something other then localhost?

Comment: The pc only has one network interface. Apache2 responds (http://localhost/ is the default apache2 website), but torrentflux is no longer available under /torrentflux, which it was before upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with command in terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/torrentflux/www/ /var/www/torrentflux
```

This links torrentflux php files to root folder of apache.